# CodeIgniter - Active Record System - Insert not working, Next Autoindex increased but no records inserted

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

```
function insert_stones($data)  
{  
    $this->db->insert("rc_stones",$data);  
    return $this->db->insert_id();  
}
```

When I call this method, I can't see a row added in the table. But the `Next Autoindex` in the MySQL table is increased. Please help me on this.

Comment: I suggest ... putting this line before the insert `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` , looking for the sql statement in the debug information at the bottom of the page, and then manually trying to insert that query that is generated and seeing what happens with the table.

Comment: I tried this one. The queries are generating correctly. When I execute the queries directly in DB it works fine too. But the Code Igniter is not executing the query or I guess it rollbacks the execution. Pls note that I can see the NextAutoIndex is increased whenever the CI executes these line.

Comment: Are you making use of Transactions?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?